MudBlazor Rating equivalent that will show fractional stars?
I use the MudBlazor MudRating control for users to rate events. Works great for that.
But I want to show the user's average rating. Which can be something like 3.7 (for a scale of 1 .. 5). Is there a way with the MudRating or other control to display the stars where one of the stars is partially filled?
